# Yii url rule with slash

Tags: php, url, yii

i need to get a http address from my url in yii , but $url parameter returns wrong value for me

config:

```
'show/c/<id:\d+>/<url:\w+>'=>'show/c',
```

Controler :

```
 public function actionC($id ,  $url)
    {
       echo $url ;

    }
```

requested url :

```
http://localhost/mink/show/c/id/6/url/https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
```

$url value is "http:"

**Edit :** 
i found what was wrong with me , i have to use

```
http://localhost/mink/c/6/https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
```

and in url  rule

```
'show/c/<id:\d+>/<url:.+>'=>'show/c',
```

it works now , ty

Comment: You need urlencode http-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
'show/c/<id:\d+>/<url:.+>'=>'show/c',
```

This should catch anything in URL, including slashes of course.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
'show/c/<id:\d+>/url/<url:[\w.:\/]+>' => 'show/c',
```

You can use regular expressions syntax in rules.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to match a static "url" string before the url variable:

```
'show/c/<id:\d+>/url/<url:.+>'=>'show/c',
                 ^^^ // Add this
```

You will also need to remove `:\w+` from the regex:

```
'show/c/<id:\d+>/url/<url:.+>'=>'show/c',
                         ^^^ // Remove this
```

**This should be your final rule:**

```
'show/c/<id:\d+>/url/<url>'=>'show/c',
```